# OpenGL quad buffered stereo doesn't show both buffers

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

When using quad buffered stereo with my application, my video card does support quad buffered stereo (Quadro 5000/PCIe/SSE2), only one buffer is displayed on the screen, i am using glut and openGL with vbos arrays, i am initialising glut this way :

```
    int type = GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STEREO;
    glutInitDisplayMode(type);
    glutInitWindowSize(width,height);

    win = glutCreateWindow(title.c_str());
    glutSetWindow(win);     
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr,"  ## ERROR: %d: %s\n",
            (int)err,(char*)gluErrorString(err));       
    }
    glutDisplayFunc(loop_function);
```

and when drawing here is how i fill both buffers :

```
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera->OnMouseMotion(sf::Vector2i(-100,0));
    camera->look();
    for (auto i = objects->cbegin(); i != objects->cend(); ++i)
        (*i)->draw(camera);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera->OnMouseMotion(sf::Vector2i(200,0));
    camera->look();
    for (auto i = objects->cbegin(); i != objects->cend(); ++i)
        (*i)->draw(camera);
    camera->OnMouseMotion(sf::Vector2i(-100,0));
    camera->look();

    glutSwapBuffers();
```

Only the right buffer (the last one called) is displayed for both eyes. I tried drawing the right buffer first but then the display is blank (none is drawn)
the OnMouseMotion does move the mouse according to the position and i know my movements are not set properly but right now i am focusing on displaying two different images, one for the right eye, one for the other one.
Is there anything i have forgotten here ? or maybe the gl calls aren't right ?

Comment: It's fairly old, so I'm not sure if it's still valid, but you may want to check out this from the NVIDIA support forum: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/483612/3d-vision/how-to-use-the-glut_stereo-display-mode-/.

Comment: You may also want to try a `glGetIntegerv(GL_STEREO, ...)` call to verify if stereo mode was successfully enabled.

Comment: You will have to enable the stereoscopic support in nvidia's driver settings, and you also have to set an appropriate mode. What kind of stereoscopic output do you want/need?

Comment: @derhass this is already on i have tried another program and it worked

Comment: @RetoKoradi ok i added your suggestion and i do get 1 as a result (so Stereo activated) and 0 when i start my program without stereo. The topic you linked isn't the same problem, i have no error or crash of the application, just a wrong display.

Comment: @derhass what i am trying to achieve is quad buffered stereoscopie, with 120Hz, displaying alternatively right and left image, but all this was already tested and does work with another program.

Comment: @user3714670: What I can tell you that in principle, it should work that way. And I can also tell you that stereoscopic context with GLUT use to work. So maybe your camera movement is not working at all and you are drawing the same image in both buffers (you could easily test by using a different clear color for each), or your driver settings are still not correct. Nvidia allows profiles per application, maybe it is not enabled in the default profile.

Comment: Apologies if you've already done so, but have you checked glGetError after rendering the left eye?

Comment: Just to narrow it down, I would make this even simpler: Set different clear colors (e.g. red and green) before clearing the left and right buffer, and don't render anything after the `glClear()`. This should make it very obvious if you get different frames for left and right.